# If use custom cluster theme, how to show the weight of each cluster?

Tags: here-api

In order to have a marker icon unique look I used a  custom cluster theme, but in this method, in the cluster does not display the weight.

```
        switch( true ){
            case weight < 100: 
                i=5;
                break;
            case weight < 1000: 
                i=4;
                break;
            case weight < 5000: 
                i=3;
                break;
            case weight < 10000: 
                i=2;
                break;
            default: 
                i=1;
                break;
        };

        var clusterMarker = new H.map.Marker(cluster.getPosition(), {
            min: cluster.getMinZoom(),
            max : cluster.getMaxZoom(),
            icon: clusterMarkers[i],
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the weight from the Data Point if required
https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-clustering-datapoint.html

wt : {number}

The weight of the data point

Comment: With this I can specify the weight of each point.
But how then to show the total value of the number of points in a cluster to cluster icon? In **clusterMarkers** only 5 types of icons (svg), depending on the size of the cluster.

Comment: ok, that would only be possible if you have the svg also available inside the theme and create icons in the theme. So you will have to trade off between the initial load time and showing the cluster weight.

Answer (score 0):

[Theming chapter](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics/clustering.html#clustering__clustering-theming) of the documentation explains in a small example how to do that.

Cluster weight can be obtained by calling the [getWeight](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-clustering-icluster.html#h-clustering-icluster__getweight) method.

Plus in order to gain performance while rendering I recommend to cache the cluster/noise point icons and reuse them for different objects.